sql retrieve all users with multiple email invitations, ordered by biggest invitation number per email, and user grouped
I have a table invitations keeping for each user the email invitations he received.
One user can have many emails, on each email can be received many invitations.
create table invitation (
    user_id INT         NOT NULL,
    email   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
 );

insert into invitation (user_id, email)
values
 (3, 'c1@gmail.com'),
 (3, 'c2@gmail.com'),
 (3, 'c3@gmail.com'),
 (1, 'a1@gmail.com'),
 (1, 'a1@gmail.com'),
 (1, 'a1@gmail.com'),
 (1, 'a2@gmail.com'),
 (2, 'b1@gmail.com'),
 (2, 'b1@gmail.com'),
 (1, 'a1@gmail.com'),
 (1, 'a2@gmail.com'),
 (2, 'b1@gmail.com'),
 (2, 'b2@gmail.com');


I want to have the top of users with the most invitations. But for a user list full situation: all emails and counter of invitations, beside the email with biggest invitation. I don't need to see users with only one invitation.
Result should be like this:
userId.  email.         counter of invitations per email
--------------------------------
 1,     'a1@gmail.com',   4,    <---- the biggest invitation number 
 1,     'a2@gmail.com',   2,    <----   followed by the rest of invitations for same user
 2,     'b1@gmail.com',   3,    <---- next biggest invitation number
 2,     'b2@gmail.com',   1.    <----   followed by the rest of invitations for same user.

I tried SQL SELECT queries with group by and order by but it's clearly more complex:
select user_id, email, count(email) as counter
from invitation
group by email, user_id
having count(email) > 1
ORDER BY counter DESC

I use PostgreSQL.
Thanks.
UPDATE:
I realised that my small example was not really exact: we can not/should not rely on the order of the user_id (can be anything there).
So I transform the example a bit:
values are
 (33, 'c1@gmail.com'),
 (33, 'c2@gmail.com'),
 (33, 'c3@gmail.com'),
 (11, 'a1@gmail.com'),
 (11, 'a1@gmail.com'),
 (11, 'a2@gmail.com'),
 (2, 'b1@gmail.com'),
 (2, 'b1@gmail.com'),
 (11, 'a1@gmail.com'),
 (11, 'a2@gmail.com'),
 (11, 'a3@gmail.com'),
 (2, 'b1@gmail.com'),
 (11, 'a1@gmail.com'),
 (2, 'b2@gmail.com');


use Count(email) to get your counts, grouping by your userid and email (as you aren't aggregating those with a formula). Then use an ORDER BY clause to achieve the ordered output you are after.

"I tried SQL SELECT ..."  So where is this try?

What is your DBMS? When asking SQL questions, always tag the request with your DBMS, so we know what SQL features are available.

If you group by user ID and email address, you get the counts that you want. Your problem is that you want to sort the users by their maximum count. A user's maximum count is
MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id)

The complete query:
SELECT user_id, email, COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM invitation
GROUP BY user_id, email
ORDER BY MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) DESC,
         user_id,
         COUNT(*) DESC,
         email;


This response stands even after the update: "don't rely on user_id order because in fact can be anything there" - so became the preferred answer :)

You can simply GROUP BY user_id AND email. Also sort by the user ascending and count descending
 SELECT user_id, email, count(*)
 FROM invitation
 GROUP BY user_id, email
 ORDER BY user_id asc, count(*) desc




User_id
Email
Count




1
a1@gmail.com
4


1
a2@gmail.com
2


2
b1@gmail.com
3


2
b2@gmail.com
1


3
c1@gmail.com
1


3
c2@gmail.com
1


3
c3@gmail.com
1




OP wants the row with the highest count first, whatever user_id. Then the rest of that user's rows.

The query is incorrect as it sorts by the wrong priority (as @jarlh mentioned). See why this is wrong. You need to change your ORDER BY clause, but then you will likely create a duplicate of this correct answer
